# How to pass a number as parameter with curl

Tags: curl, types

I'm trying to pass a number as a parameter using curl

```
curl -F number=10.3 http://localhost:8080/some/route
```

but when I check the type of number I get string. How can I ensure that number will be a Float?

Comment: You just did, but you can never be sure that everybody will. There's nothing that you can or you even should try to do on the client side.
Your app should know what to expect, validate and convert. You didn't mentioned anything about your app - where you checked it's type ?

Comment: I think, if you use `-F` option you suggest using a form that posts data to server side. So there's not an html input of number|float type. this value has to be treated on server side.